# Georeferencing CAD drawings without preserving aspect ratio

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, dwg

I have a CAD drawing (DWG) format that I would like to georeference to my basemaps that are projected in UTM coordinates. This drawing is done to scale without any geographic referencing.

In ArcGIS Desktop, the georeferncing toolbar allows for 2 control points in the CAD georeferencing process, so as to preserve the aspect ratio. I would like to introduce skewness because of the projected coordinate system.

Advice required on the spatial alignment of the CAD file to a projected basemap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the CAD data is imported you can use the Spatial Adjustment Toolbar methods Rubbersheet or Affine Transformation to refine the georeferencing.